# What was Kuroko's real name?

Tags: kuroko-no-basket

I really love anime and I can't stop watching them. Among them, the anime I like most is *The Basketball Which Kuroko Plays*. I really want to know Kuroko's real name.

Comment: I don't understand why you had this question. It's not like Kuroko uses a pseudonym or conceals his name or anything like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're asking about the character, his full name is **Tetsuya Kuroko**.

If you're asking about the voice actor, it's **Kensho Ono** for the Japanese version, and **Adrien Solis** for the French version.

This can all be confirmed on Tetsuya Kuroko's [MyAnimeList Page](http://myanimelist.net/character/18769/Tetsuya_Kuroko)

Comment: @LittleNecklace No problem. if it answers your question, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted.